# BindingResolutionException Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel-4, dependency-injection, model-binding

I have strugging with below error. It is not about interface error but model error. I don't know what wrong in below code.

```
Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException

Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable.
```

I don't have any idea to deal with this.

I have company model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Eloquent{
   protected $softDelete = true;
   protected $table = "companies";
   protected $fillable = [];
   protected $guarded = [];
}
```

That is companyrepositoryinterface

```
namespace ohbt\Repositories;
 interface CompanyRepositoryInterface{
 }
```

That is companyrepository

```
namespace ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents;

use Company;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ohnt\Services\Validator\CompanyValidator as Validator;
use ohbt\Repositories\CompanyRepositoryInterface as CompanyRepositoryInterface;

class CompanyRepository extends AbstractRepository implements CompanyRepositoryInterface{

   protected $company;
   protected $validator;

    public function __constructor(Model $company, Validator $validator){
        $this->company = $company;
        parent::__construct($this->company);
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function create(array $attributes){
    if($this->validator->isValid($attributes)){
        $this->company->create($attributes);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }

    public function getMessages(){
       return $this->validator->getMessages();
    }
}
```

And My repositoryservices provider already added to app/config/app.php

```
namespace ohbt\Repositories;
 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoriesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

protected $defer = false;

public function boot()
{
    //
}

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('VehicleRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\VehicleRepository');

    $this->app->bind('UserRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\UserRepository');

    $this->app->bind('CompanyRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\CompanyRepository');
}

public function provides()
{
    return array();
}

}
```

Really appreciate any suggest and help. Thank advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I donn't think this is the appropriate or good solution for Model Instantiating problem. But It solved my recent problem.

I described specific file and Model in RepossitoryServiceProvider. But other Binding work while this one have problem made no sense.

Here is my solution

```
 use \Company;   //Company Model added 
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 use ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\CompanyRepository;  //Company Repository added.

class RepositoriesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

protected $defer = false;

public function boot()
{
    //
}

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('ohbt\Repositories\BaseRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\AbstractRepository');

    $this->app->bind('VehicleRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\VehicleRepository');

    $this->app->bind('UserRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\UserRepository');

    $this->app->bind('GuestRepositoryInterface', 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\GuestRepository');

     /**
      * Comment out the previous binding function. 
      * $this->app->bind('CompanyRepositoryInterface',
      * 'ohbt\Repositories\Eloquents\CompanyRepository');
      * directly return Repository Object rather than directory of Repository of Model
      **/
    $this->app->bind('CompanyRepositoryInterface', function()
    {
        return new CompanyRepository( new Company );
    });
}

public function provides()
{
    return array();
}

}
```

In this case, we have to declare all model and repository file to bind with IoC. That is not a good idea. So Appreciatively welcome advanced solution or answer for better approached.

Comment: Now I m facing problem with company validator service which is use in companyrepository. 
       `
        $this->validator->isValid($attributes); 
      `

    I got "Trying to get property of non-object" Error. 
Please help appropriate solution. Why this Interface could not be bind as other?

Comment: Did you add RepositoriesServiceProvider to the providers array in app.php ?